# Why is temperature considered as an important factor in deciding chemical reaction kinetics?

Tags: kinetics, temperature

According to the Arrhenius equation, the rate of reaction is proportional to $e^{-1/RT}$.

Here is a plot of the equation and its derivative with respect to temperature, both with respect to temperature. All constants are set to unity.

[image]

It seems to suggest that there is almost no change in the rate of reaction with increasing temperature except at very-low-temperature range.

Then, why is temperature considered an important factor in deciding the kinetics of a chemical reaction?

Comment: The Arrhenius eqn. describes how the *rate constant* changes with temperature as $k=A\exp(-E_a/(RT))$ where $E_a$ is the activation energy (an energy barrier) and *A* is a constant. At higher temperatures more molecules (by the Boltzmann distribution) have enough energy to surmount the activation barrier and so reaction becomes faster. Negative temperature as in your figure do not make sense. At very high temperatures the exponential tends to 1 as all  molecules have enough energy to exceed the barrier energy and so the rate constant tends to *A*.

Comment: It is possible to produce negative temperatures, (inverted population) such as in a laser, in certain NMR experiments, and in a chemical laser. But the first two are not chemical reactions and the latter the population inversion is in the products of an exothermic reaction. To answer your last question the rate constant does change by a large amount from low to high temperatures, basically from zero to from finite limiting value at high temperature.

Comment: If the activation energy is lower (<<50kJ/mol),  then temperature has a much lower effect than when activation energy is higher (>>100kJ/mol). Your comment would be true for the former case